# How to search github repo by collaborators

Tags: github, github-api

Is there any way I can list all the repositories where a particular user is listed as collaborator. I can see that I can list all the repos owned by a user and all the collaborators in a repo, but can't find a way to get all the repos where a user is a collaborator.

Am I missing something or its not available?

Edit: I intend to do it using Github API v3.

Comment: Such queries are not possible currently. You could use data in the (Unofficial) GitHub archive, for public repositories.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you go to your github dashboard (https://github.com/dashboard) you can see all the repositories you contribute to on the upper right side.

Still, to answer your question, if you visit a users profile (https://github.com/username), there will be a list of repositories the user contributes to in the upper right corner.

However, there is also the possibility that this list will be empty because the repos that this user contributes to are private. You will not see the private repos in this list, except given the fact that you can access those as well.

Comment: actually I wanted to do it through the API call using github API v3, I'll update the question accordingly as I guess I haven't been very clear with that.